# Styled-components not applying style on fragment excluded from initial render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

In the example below, the background style on the `StyledButton` is not being applied. It seems to happen when a fragment is not included in the initial render of the component. For example, if we were to just render the StyledComponent here, it would have a black background as expected. Is this expected behaviour?

NB: I am using create-react-app with Typescript

```
const StyledButton = styled.button`
  background: black;
`

function TestComponent(props) {
  const [x, setX] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setX(false)
    }, 600)
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout)
    }
  }, [])
  if (x) {
    return <>{'test'}</>
  }
  return <StyledButton>test</StyledButton>
}
```

Comment: The example you have given seems to [work fine](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cux4ab)

Comment: @Agney If that is the case, possibly Typescript compiler is messing things up

Comment: @alsco77 Have you inspected the DOM confirming that the button has a class applied to it that contains the `background` property? In a sandbox your example works just fine.

Comment: @trixn  This seems to only be happening when using Brave browser. I just checked in Chrome and its working fine there....

Answer (score 0):

Hi i believe this is becuase you are checking the state outside of the render function so it is not rechecked each rerender, the following code should help. Let us know if you have any questions.

```
const StyledButton = styled.button`
  background: black;
`

function TestComponent(props) {
  const [x, setX] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setX(false)
    }, 600)
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout)
    }
  }, [])

  return(
    <>
      {x ? <>{'test'}</> :  <StyledButton>test</StyledButton>}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: There is no rule against checking state outside `return`

Comment: As this is a functional component the whole component is the "render" function. You example is equivalent to the orginal code except that it adds a fragment.

Comment: But yes the orginal example does work for me also, the version I have given should still work though and is a little more readable (imo)